# KeyError when trying to get token

Tags: python, python-requests

```
res = s.post('https://api-gw.interneturok.ru/api/v2/psp/tokens', json=payload)
```

Return this

```
{'status': '200_OK', 'data': {'psp': {'code': 200, 'response': {'data': {'access_token': 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvYXBpLXBzcC5pbnRlcm5ldHVyb2sucnVcL2FwaVwvdjJcL3Rva2VucyIsImlhdCI6MTY2NDgxODExNSwiZXhwIjoxNjY0ODIxNzE1LCJuYmYiOjE2NjQ4MTgxMTUsImp0aSI6IjdjdWRBckJWWHZnQVhQTXQiLCJzdWIiOjI5MTY0NDIsInBydiI6IjIzYmQ1Yzg5NDlmNjAwYWRiMzllNzAxYzQwMDg3MmRiN2E1OTc2ZjcifQ.N8dyFXzTtoLH5gx7TPNzNCdXQCXF4PlisttUuOPFtkk', 'access_type': 'Bearer', 'expires_in': 3600}, 'status': '0000_OK', 'user': {'permissions_updated_at': None}}}}}
```

Then I do this thing

```
s.headers.update({'authorization': json.loads(res.content)['acces_token']})
```

It should login me to my account, but this happens:

```
     s.headers.update({'authorization': json.loads(res.content)['acces_token']})
KeyError: 'acces_token'
```

Comment: The `access_token` is buried in that json object/nested-dictionary. `json.loads(res.content)['data']['psp']['response']['data']['access_token']` would be the path to that entry.

Comment: Sorry, I am dumb

Comment: Nah. You've never dealt with this before. Now you have. It's a win win. Best of luck with the rest of the coding.

Comment: Also, `access_token` has two `s`.